# Can't install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 16.04 due to redundant partition flags

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I've a working version of Ubuntu 16.04. on my Acer Aspire E15 and I wish to install Windows 10 as a second os (dualboot).

I know that there are many threads about this topic, but I couldn't apply most of the suggested solutions to my system or they just didn't work.

Unfortunately, I'm no expert in partitioning and what it's all about.. Now I'm at my wit's end.

- Windows 10 is on a bootable, FAT32 formatted USB drive
- My BIOS is on UEFI (the other option would be Legacy), and Secure Boot is disabled
- Boot order is 1. USB Drive, 2. My (only) hard drive, (and all the other stuff like network boot and whatsoever)
- I used gparted while booting from an Ubuntu Live USB drive to free up some space. When I start gparted I get this error *physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512*. I read that this error can be ignored. My partitions now look like this: [image]
- Then I boot from the Windows 10 USB Drive and select the unallocated space to install Windwos 10 into it.
- After a short moment it jumps to the next window where it says "Copying files", but then it breaks. The error reads (it's in German, so I try to translate it as faithful as possible)

**It was noticed, that the EFI-systempartition was not formatted as NTFS. Please format the EFI-systempartition as FAT32 and restart the installation**

- Going back one window where I choose on what partition I want to install Win10 are now 4 new partitions. In my case *Disk 0 Partition 6* is the only one which I could choose to install Win10 on. But when I highlight it, the next button stays unclickable and a info message next to it says

**No new partition could be created or no existing partition was found. Further information can be found in the protocol files from the setup**(sidenote: where do I find those protocols?)

In one thread I read it was due to I booted Windows10 from a USB 3.0 port which might cause errors -> didn't help. Then I formatted the unallocated space to NTFS beforehand and tried again -> didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reported this Windows error message (translated from German):

> It was noticed, that the EFI-systempartition was not formatted as NTFS. Please format the EFI-systempartition as FAT32 and restart the installation

This makes no sense; the first sentence implies that the EFI System Partition (ESP) should be NTFS, but the second sentence explicitly says it should be FAT32. Your GParted output shows that the ESP (`/dev/sda1` in your case) *is* FAT32, which is correct (the ESP *must* be FAT, and the last I checked, Windows expects FAT32 specifically).

There may be a translation issue here -- if the word "not" is removed from the first sentence, it is at least internally consistent and consistent with what EFI requires. That said, your ESP (`/dev/sda1`) is FAT32, not NTFS.

Looking more closely at your GParted display, though, you have two partitions that are marked as ESPs -- `/dev/sda1` (which *is* your ESP) and `/dev/sda2` (your Ubuntu root [`/`] partition). It's possible that `/dev/sda2` having the "boot, esp" flag set is what's causing the problem. Thus, I recommend you remove that flag. (In this case, "boot" and "esp" are redundant flags. Both identify the ESP partition type code. You could do the same thing in `gdisk` by changing the type code from EF00 to 8300.) Be sure to change the type code of `/dev/sda2` *only* -- *do not* change the type code of `/dev/sda1`. It might be worth deleting the partitions that the Windows installer created, too, and let it create them anew when you try again. Without seeing what it created, I can't know whether what it did was appropriate; it's conceivable that the Windows installer created something it shouldn't have because of its confusion over `/dev/sda2` being marked as an ESP.

Note that Ubuntu doesn't care about partition type codes, so this error wouldn't have affected Ubuntu. Windows is more picky about such things.

Comment: It seemed nonsensical to me, too, but this is what the error message read.
"Es wurde festgestellt, dass die EFI-Systempartition nicht als NTFS formatiert worden ist. Formatieren Sie die EFI-Systempartition als FAT32, und starten Sie die Installation erneut."
Google gives "It was found that the EFI system partition was not formatted as NTFS. Format the EFI system partition as FAT32, and then restart the installation."
I'll try the thing with the flags when I'm back on this machine.
I've deleted the partitions the windows installer created. Iif it fails again, I'll post a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

While booted to gparted, choose the unallocated partition and format it to NTFS, and then try setup again. I believe bare minimum the unallocated space has to have a partition created or it is basically unrecognized, ignored, or cannot be used.

Comment: I tried it this way, too (as mentioned at the end of my question), but it didn't work, either.